# How to decode html and javascript characters in PHP DOMDocument object

Tags: php, domdocument

I am working with PHP DOMDocument (PHP 7.3), and I read some HTML code into `$html` variable.

```
 $html="<html>      
  <body>
    <img src="home/img.jpg">
     <?php echo "hello"?>
 <body>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var s=1;
     alert("hi"+s);
   });
 </script>
 </html>";
```

Then I'm creating a DOMDocument from the variable:

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
 @$dom->loadHTML( $html);
 $m = $dom->saveHTML();
```

But when I save this code into a file, JavaScript arithmetic operators are missing, and also the URLs inside the code get percent encoded, for example the `src` of the image is changed to `"home%5Cimg.jpg"`.

I've tried to decode the URLs like this:

```
$m = urldecode($dom->saveHTML());
```

But the issue is not resolved. Is there any method to save the enitre HTML code with out encoding the URLs and loosing JS operators?

Comment: In the code above, your `$html` string uses double quotes in the string so this will cause problems.  Also not sure if you expect the `<?php` part inside to be processed properly.  BUT if you remove all of the issues with this string, you should get no *encryption* and the code should be the same.

Comment: Yes, PHP HTML parser is a bit ... say insufficient. I'm not sure what "_encrypting_" here means, but the parser parses also inline JS to HTML, you can't include inline JS to the documents parsed with PHP parser.

Comment: @NigelRen also for testing i placed this php html code inside a file for reading but both methods causing same encryption issues

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by encryption issues, can you show the results in the question.

Comment: @Teemu the word Encytipon that i used here is , the img src link get changing like this   "home%5Cimg.jpg"

Comment: @NigelRen  the word Encytipon that i used here is , the img src link get changing like this "home%5Cimg.jpg"

Comment: @Adwaith That’s encoding, not encryption.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce your issue with PHP 7.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Teemu php version is php7.3

Comment: Like said in my first comment, PHP parser can't handle inline JS correctly. I haven't noticed missing operators, but `>` operators are treated like tag closing tokens, and that messes up the page badly. Save your scripts in external .js files, and use `src` attribute of `script` element to load the script on the page. I'm using somewhat similar code, the only difference being that I'm decoding the HTML entities before flushing (`$flush = html_entity_decode($page, ENT_HTML5);`), but that's done because of scandic characters. I can't reproduce the URL encoding issue.